# why does numpy normalize these equivalent arrays differently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, precision, normalize

The two arrays `raw_document_scores` and `raw_doc_scores1 are equal`, evidenced by `raw_document_scores==raw_doc_scores1` returning an array of all trues. However, when I check if

```
raw_document_scores/np.linalg.norm(raw_document_scores, 1, axis=1).reshape(-1,1) \
== raw_doc_scores1/np.linalg.norm(raw_doc_scores1, 1, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
```

I get false for some entries. I subtracted the two arrays to see how much each entry differs by, and it's less than e-18, so they are approximately equal. However, why are they not exactly equal, if the input arrays are exactly equal? Are the first two arrays not actually equal, and python/numpy is lying when it says all their entries are equal? Here is an image to show what happened.

[difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mYLJ.png)

Comment: MWE, please....

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. No images, no links please.

Comment: At the minimum, please show the complete output of `raw_document_scores` and `raw_doc_scores1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided any details about your input data, the only way is to give an answer is to guess at what's actually wrong. Here's a scenario that matches yours; generated on 64-bit Python:

```
>>> A = np.array(np.random.random([10, 3])*10, dtype=int)
>>> B = np.array(A, dtype='float32')
>>> A == B
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])

>>> np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1) == np.linalg.norm(B, axis=1)
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False])
```

I'm guessing it's the data types that are mismatched between `raw_document_scores` and `raw_doc_scores1`. For reference:

```
>>> C = np.copy(A)
>>> np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1) == np.linalg.norm(C, axis=1)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```